# Windows 10 pairs with phone bluetooth and can transfer files but cannot have active connection?

Tags: windows, windows-10, android, bluetooth

I have paired my android phone with my Windows 10 via bluetooth and am able to send and receive files. However I cannot have an active bluetooth connection between the devices.

My goal is to have my pc as a trusted device on my phone so that I can have my phone unlocked whenever it is near my pc.

How can I get my phone to have an active bluetooth connection with my pc? Or what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: There must be 2 applications that will kjeep connection active. First runs on cell and the other runs on PC. It doe snot matter if it is built-in application sor any custom. There is no way to keep connection active if the connection actually does not exists (nothing connected).

Comment: I see. Can you suggest any applications that can just idle a connection? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately no but any should be ok. Probably Bluetooth File Explorer or something like that.